# Enter article title from Joomla as title for event creation in EasySocial

Tags: php, joomla

I am trying to fill the article title automatically into an event creation form inside a EasySocial stream module. Therefor I need to insert the current article title as title variable inside the .php file that creates the event.

If I just try

```
  $title = TITLE;
```

it works and the event gets the title "TITLE". But if I try to catch the current article title first and output the article title as title variable, it does not work. Obviously I am doing something wrong but I can not discover how to get it working. I got this so far:

```
$articleTitle = '';
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
if ( ($id = (int) $input->get('id')) )
 {
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('title')->from('#__content')->where('id = ' . $id);
$db->setQuery($query);
$articleTitle = $db->loadResult();
 }
echo $articleTitle;
```

This is working and I can see the article title on my site. But when I try to set it as $title to be set, it is not working any longer:

```
$title = $articleTitle;
```

Any advice what I am doing wrong at the final step?

Answer (score 0):

Your articleTitle is not string but db result

```
if (!$result) {
    echo 'No title ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; // title
```

Answer (score 0):

$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$title = $doc->getTitle();

$title equals title of the page

Don't forget echo before $title